# Floppy Power Connector vs Molex

Tags: power-supply, molex

Reading about different equipment and a review I read said that the hardware uses a `Floppy Power Connector` how is that different than a Molex connector and if the hardware needs a Floppy Power Connector and I only have a Molex connector will it work?

Comment: A “floppy power connector” is actually called a **Berg** connector.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main difference between them is the size. 
[Here](http://pinouts.ru/Power/SmallPower_pinout.shtml) you can see the details of the floppy connector and [here](http://pinouts.ru/Power/BigPower_pinout.shtml) you can see the specifics of the standard connector.

Basically, they're electrically same, but the floppy is physically smaller. Don't expect to connect the device which uses the floppy connector to the standard one without some hacks...

Also are you sure that you don't have a floppy connector? At lest one has been on power supplies for long time. If you really don't have one, you could try finding an adapter and using it for the device or making one yourself from an old power supply.

Comment: I probably have one but wasn't sure but you supplied the info I was looking for. Thanks!